# Is it possible to get the app icon of a built-in app on iOS?

Tags: ios, icon

I would like to get an iOS app icon from a built in app, like Settings, ideally not including the app icon mask.

On macOS you can select the app in Finder, choose Get Info, click the icon, copy it to the clipboard, then paste it into Preview for example to get a 1024x1024 png. Is there a way to achieve the same thing but for iOS apps even ones that are built in?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### In a word, no.

Not on iOS as there is no way to get to that particular icon without jailbreaking the device.

However there are 3rd-party tools (iMazing is one of them) that allow you to copy apps from the phone to the Mac and explore the filesystem on the phone.

Not sure if they will give you what you want but I do believe that the apps that do this have demo modes that will let you find out.